# Magento 2.1 : Calendar Frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery, calendar

I have some data on front-end , which I want to show on specific days in the calendar. I got this code to show the calendar on the front end .

```
 <?php 
      $a = 'some text';
      $b = 'some other text'
 ?>

<div id="xxx" name="xxx"></div>
<script>
 require([
      "jquery",
      "mage/calendar"
 ], function($){
     $("#xxx").calendar({
          buttonText:"<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
     });
   });
```

Can any one guide , how to customize calendar days to show data on the calendar.Or is it more advisable to use an external calendar plugin??

Comment: Hi Verdu, Please follow the below link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82264/magento-2-adding-calender-to-custom-frontend-form

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code, I hope it will work for you.

```
Calendar.setup({
        inputField: "delivery_date",
        ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y",
        showsTime: false,
        button: "delivery_date",
        align: "Bl",
        singleClick : true,
        dateText: 'specific days'
    })
```