# Datepicker Options in Knockout JS Binding is not working

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs, datepicker

In my HTML frontend form, I have included a date picker using Knockout JS data binding. But the date picker options is not loading. I want my date format should be like "02-Dec-1991". I gave my HTML element like this:

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" id="customer-dob" name="dob" value="" data-validate="{'required-entry':true}" data-bind="value: dob,datepicker: dob,datePickeroptions: {
                    dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    maxDate: new Date(),
                    datePickerPlaceholder: 'dd/M/yy' 
                    }"/>
```

Please suggest me how to make this work?

Comment: which type of format display in datepicker?

Comment: It is help for me hope it will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84879/43587

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya : Currently the date picker uses the format " mm-dd-yyyy"

Comment: @SagarDobariya : Did u really used that solution in your "html" file with Knockout JS ?? or in your phtml file ? Because I have to use the datepicker in html file with Knockout JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i used:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers['datepicker'] = {
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        /* Initialize datepicker with some optional options */
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datePickeroptions || {},
            prop = valueAccessor(),
            $elem = $(element);

        prop($elem.val());

        $elem.datepicker(options);

        /* Handle the field changing */
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            prop($elem.datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        /* Handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding) */
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $elem.datepicker("destroy");
        });
    },
    'update': function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            $elem = $(element),
            current = $elem.datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $elem.datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To make your code working you have to write below code in your ".js" file.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
            init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                var $el = $(element);

                //initialize datepicker with some optional options
                var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
                $el.datepicker(options);

                //handle the field changing
                ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
                });

                //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
                ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
                    $el.datepicker("destroy");
                });

            },
            update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                    $el = $(element),
                    current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

                if (value - current !== 0) {
                    $el.datepicker("setDate", value);   
                }
            }
        };

return Component.extend({
//....
dob: ko.observable(new Date())
//....
});
```

Reference from: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NAgNV/

Comment: It's not working. My Knockout Html file is form.html and its Js file is form.js. I have added the above code in form.js but nothing happened.

Comment: @Anjana It depends where you have added your code.Can you please post your form.js so that I can review it.This is working code for me.

Comment: Hi @PareshaU, How can I set the initial value to null in the text input while the page loads.

Comment: @Haritha you can just write this line like "dob: ko.observable()"  instead of "dob: ko.observable(new Date())"

Comment: Is there a way that default opening of the date picker can be restricted on page load? @PareshaU

Comment: @Haritha, you mean you want to disable text box where we click to choose date picker?

Comment: @PareshaU, When showTime is set, the datepicker stays open when the page is loaded.

Comment: where you want to show can you please share your code?

Comment: Hello @P_U in Magento 2 we need to date piker but still input type=" text" then used before code but still here throw console err allBindingsAccessor can you help this matter

Answer (score 0):

The Solution I Used:

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" id="customer-dob" name="dob" value="" data-validate="{'required-entry':true}" data-bind="value: dob, datepicker: {storage: dob, options: { dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'}}"/>
```

Make Sure `dob` should be defined as observable.

Please let me know if it works for you.

Thanks